# sites with breadcrumb navigation similar to this?

Tags: ux-designer

I'm trying to find a way to implement location-based breadcrumb navigation. I visited the [Toronto2015 site](http://results.toronto2015.org/IRS/en/tennis/event-overview-men-s-singles.htm), and it gave me an idea of how it could be done.

So let's say that "Schedule" is a country, "Athletes" a state, and "Men's Events" a city. When I click the arrow next to "Men's Events", I'll see a popup where I can do a selection. In my case, within the popup I'll be able to select another country, state, city with a "search" button.

I'm looking for sites that do something similar. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: that is NOT a breadcrumb, it's just a popup with inline `li` elements, what you're looking for is known as a mega-menu

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. Take a look at [this article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/03/breadcrumbs-in-web-design-examples-and-best-practices/), specifically Section 5 on "Breadcrumbs with Subnavigation" A few examples there. Lonely Planet has a model I haven't seen before. Not sure how well it works for users, as the traditional order of hierarchy is reversed...